# Value of integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> The value of 
>   $$\int_0^\infty t^{-3/2}\left(1-e^{-t}\right)\,dt=$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXYS7.jpg)

Applying integration by parts or using any kind of substitution is not working.

My attempt:

Splitting the integrands and integrating t^-1.5 over 0 to infinity gives infinity.

Now, treating t^-1.5 and (1- exp(-t)) as two separate functions and applying integration by parts also results in same problem.

Ps: This is not a homework question.

Comment: You should still include your thoughts and efforts in 
this and future posts. Formatting tips 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: ohh yes i will include them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integration by parts gives
$$
-\left.2t^{-1/2}(1-e^{-t})\right|_0^{\infty}+2\int_0^{\infty}t^{-1/2}e^{-t}\ dt.
$$
The first term vanishes both at $0$ and $\infty$ (observe that $1-e^{-t}$ vanishes to first order at $0$). To evaluate the second term, consider the substitution $u=\sqrt t$ to express it in terms of the integral
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u^2}\ du.
$$
This is a [famous integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), and the trick to evaluating it is to square it then convert to polar coordinates. This is where the $\sqrt{\pi}$ comes from.

Comment: Thanx, i was doubtful regarding the first part , now its clear :)